# How can I remotely view my Apple TV from my computer?

Tags: appletv, remote-control

I would like to be able to view my Apple TV from my computer remotely (similar to Smart View app by Samsung, but in reverse) so I can use an automation tool. What tools are available that allow me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

If you can Jailbreak it (basically atv2 at the time of writing) I believe you can install the Veency package and connect via VNC